# Calcular el numero de periodo del mes

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, function

Quisiera saber si existe alguna función que me diga que numero de periodo estamos, por ejemplo, cada mes tiene 2 periodos, por lo que si queremos el periodo hasta el día 25 de Octubre, el periodo es 20, si el día es 13, el periodo es 19(porque la quincena no ha pasado), todo depende si la quincena ya pasó, para esta fecha, 22 de Noviembre, el periodo es el 22. Si la fecha fuera 1 de Diciembre, el periodo es el 23 y asi sucesivamente.

Existe alguna función que indique el periodo en el que nos encontramos?

Comment: Qué has investigado?

Comment: si si existe una funcion